# How to secure exchange hot wallet keys

Tags: wallet-security, bitcoinjs

Am currently working on an exchange, am building the hot wallet using `bitcoinjs-lib`. I generate my wallet pub /sec keys and addresses using this library (I don't want to use wallet.dat file).

Now is there a way I can encrypt the secret keys and at the same time make them available when there is need to sign transaction for users who wish to withdraw funds ?